# Matching identical elements in different lists and replacing old with new elements

Tags: python, list, split, match, arcpy

Hi everyone, 

I'm a python beginner, trying to come up with a simple solution to the following problem.

I have two lists. Each is one column, and numerous rows of dir/path/filename.ext

A is the old list
B is the new list

I’d like to create a new list, which would be a result of this workflow:
1. Find file name in the first line in list A
2. Find a matching file name anywhere in list B (this would be unique so no problems with duplicates)
3.  If match found, replace A's path with B’s path
4. Iterate through all list A’s rows.

The final results should be a list variable where all the old paths (A) were replaced with the new paths (B). If no match was found, the old path would stay the same.

**Example:**

**List A**
D:\Maps\Expeditions.shp
D:\Maps\Routes.shp
D:\Maps\Stations.shp
D:\Maps\Vegetation.shp

**List B**
C:\Project\Stations.shp
C:\Project\Routes.shp
C:\Project\Expeditions.shp
C:\Project\Lakes.shp
C:\Project\Mountains.shp

**New list**
C:\Project\Expeditions.shp
C:\Project\Routes.shp
C:\Project\Stations.shp
D:\Maps\Vegetation.shp

Many thanks!

J

Answer (score 1):

```
# function to return filename from path
fname = lambda x: x.split("\\")[-1]

# list of filepaths in list a that have no corresponding file name in list b
r1 = [x for x in lista if not fname(x) in map(fname, listb)]

# list of filepaths in list b that have a corresponding file name in list a
r2 = [x for x in listb if fname(x) in map(fname, lista)]

result = r1 + r2
```

will give the desired result:

```
['D:\\Maps\\Vegetation.shp', 'C:\\Project\\Stations.shp', 'C:\\Project\\Routes.shp', 'C:\\Project\\Expeditions.shp']
```

Comment: This answer has some good ideas. :) But every data item has `fname` called on it twice and, even worse, the matching is performed via linear scans through lists. What if there are a few thousand files to process? Even ignoring scalability, the code would read so much better with dicts: `dicta = { fname(f):f for f in lista }`. Ditto for `dictb`. And then matching logic similar to (but simpler than) what you already have. Just a suggestion.